# How to format latex-quality math code in Mathematica?

Tags: output-formatting

I'm giving a presentation with a notebook as a slide show and would like some of my equations to appear professional.  For example I have an integral function with a square root in the denominator but the integral symbol and fraction with the square root appears odd, not sized correctly, an unprofessional-looking when I try to display it with Text and Style.  Here is an example of my code.  Could someone suggest a way to make this expression appear latex-quality in a notebook?  I only want to display it and several others as a label underneath plots.

Thanks for reading.

```
Text[Style["\[Zeta]=\[Xi]+\[Eta]I=\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\n StyleBox[\"\
[Integral]\",\nFontSize->36], \"0\", \"z\"]\)\!\(\*FractionBox[\(A\), 
SqrtBox[\(\((1 - \*SuperscriptBox[\(w\), \(2\)])\) \((\*SuperscriptBox[\(a\), 
\\(2\)] - \*SuperscriptBox[\(w\), \(2\)])\)\)]]\)\[DifferentialD]w", 16]]
```

Comment: Have you seen [`TraditionalForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TraditionalForm.html).

Comment: Have you seen [MaTeX](http://szhorvat.net/pelican/latex-typesetting-in-mathematica.html)?

Comment: I'm familiar with MaTeX but not sure I could use it as this is going to be a presentation at the Mathematica conference in October and I have to have everything on a thumbdrive so don't want to carry any extra software that  I may have problems with.  This from a previous reply is close to perfect:

Comment: Row[{Spacer[100],Style[HoldForm[f[w]=A/Sqrt[(1-w^2)(a^2-w^2)]],20,Bold]//TraditionalForm,Spacer[150],Style[
    HoldForm[\[Zeta] = \[Xi]+\[Eta] I = Integrate[A/(Sqrt[(1 - w^2)(a^2 - w^2)]), {w,0,z}]], 20,Bold]//TraditionalForm,Spacer[150],
    Column[{Style[HoldForm[\[Eta]=\!\(
\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(\[Integral]\), \(0\), \(\[Alpha]\)]\(
\*FractionBox[\(1\), \(R + \[Rho]\ cos \((t)\)\)] \[DifferentialD]t\)\)],30,Bold]//TraditionalForm,Style[HoldForm[\[Xi]=\[Phi]],30,Bold]//TraditionalForm}]}]

Comment: I think `Matex` should be integrated into Mathematica, so you do not have to worry about carrying additional software such as texlive, etc... to make it work. Matlab allows one to display labels and titles using Latex. It is build-into Matlab.  But why can't you create the plots at home and save them as images? Then during presentations, you just show them? Why run the code to generate the plots again? Or are you making changes at presentation time so plots will be different?

Comment: Yes, I am saving the three plots as images in my Notebook and then using the Row command to label the relevant functions which pertain to them.  Perhaps though I should just use Graphics to save the expressions inside the plots but they are both Graphics and Graphics3D and do not wish the labels to (interactively) rotate with the 3D graphics images.   May need to work on it a bit further.  Would really like the expressions to look latex quality.  I could ask the group at Wolfram if MaTeX is suitable for a presentation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my opinion this will give somewhat better looking typesetting than the code you posted in a comment to your question.

```
Style[Row[
  {Spacer[60],
   HoldForm[f[w] = A/Sqrt[(1 - w^2) (a^2 - w^2)]],
   Spacer[150],
   HoldForm[ζ = ξ + η I = Integrate[A/(Sqrt[(1 - w^2) (a^2 - w^2)]), {w, "\[ThinSpace]0", "\[ThinSpace]z"}]],
   Spacer[100],
   Column[
     {HoldForm[η = Integrate[1/(R + ρ Cos[t]), t]],
      HoldForm[ξ = ϕ]}],
   Spacer[20]}}],
  20] // TraditionalForm
```

[image: math]

It's not LaTeX quality, but it's about a close as the built-in typesetting can get.